# `org-emphasis-regexp-components`: are there undocumented requirements for the entries in this list?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

To put my question quickly: are there some unwritten requirements for the entries in the list `org-emphasis-regexp-components`, specifically for the first two entries `pre` and `post` (which respectively list the characters allowed before emphasised text and after emphasised text)?

I have seen discussion of this list before, notably in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54715,
but I seem to be hitting some sort of undocumented edge case that prevents my edits from functioning.

Now, my specific context. I am trying to find a **easily readable** way to allow

- spaces, opening delimiters and dashes before emphasised text, and
- spaces, closing delimiters, dashes and punction after emphasised text.

To that end, I have set

- `"[:space:]({[“-–—"` for `pre` and
- `"[:space:])}]”-–—.?!,;:"` for `post`,
  in what I believe is a readable manner (see below).

With these settings, placing a space, opening parenthesis `(`, bracket `[` or brace `{` before emphasised text does not interfere with the emphasis. But placing any other character does. I would expect that the left double quote `“`, dash `-`, endash `–` and emdash `—` should work, since they are included in `pre`, but they don't.

And placing *any* character after emphasised text breaks the emphasis.

Here is the actual code setting the values.

```
(setcar org-emphasis-regexp-components
  (concat
    "[:space:]"
    (string
      ;; Opening delimiters; the comments prevent match-parens from getting mad .
      ?( ;;)
      ?{ ;;}
      ?[ ;;]
      ?“ ;;”
      ;; Dashes
      ?- ?– ?—)))
(setcar (nthcdr 1 org-emphasis-regexp-components)
  (concat
    "[:space:]"
    (string
      ;; Closing delimiters, with matching comments as above.
         ;;(
      ?) ;;{
      ?} ;;[
      ?] ;;“
      ?”
      ;; Dashes
      ?- ?– ?—
      ;; Punctuation
      ?. ?? ?! ?, ?; ?:)))
```

And for reference, here is the documentation for `org-emphasis-regexp-components`. It does not mention any required layout for the definition of `pre` and `post`.

```
org-emphasis-regexp-components is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.

Documentation:
Components used to build the regular expression for emphasis.
This is a list with five entries.  Terminology:  In an emphasis string
like " *strong word* ", we call the initial space PREMATCH, the final
space POSTMATCH, the stars MARKERS, "s" and "d" are BORDER characters
and "trong wor" is the body.  The different components in this variable
specify what is allowed/forbidden in each part:

pre          Chars allowed as prematch.  Beginning of line will be allowed too.
post         Chars allowed as postmatch.  End of line will be allowed too.
border       The chars *forbidden* as border characters.
body-regexp  A regexp like "." to match a body character.  Don’t use
             non-shy groups here, and don’t allow newline here.
newline      The maximum number of newlines allowed in an emphasis exp.
```

What am I missing that is causing this not to work?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the emacs SE rather than SO?

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after writing this question, I did what I should have done in the first place, and tried adding fewer characters to `pre` and `post`. And lo and behold, it was the `[`, `]`, and `-` entries causing the issues.

Paying closer attention to the previous discussion of `org-emphasis-regexp-components` (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54715), these strings are somehow combined into a large and complicated regular expression. And it would seem that errant brackets and dashes may be mistaken for special characters in that regular expression, and so cause problems.

As per [NickD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2561714/nickd)'s comment, in fact what is required is to follow the convention for regular expressions, so

1. if including a dash `-`, it must be the first or the last element of the string, and
2. if including a closing brace `]`, it must be the first element of the string.

When all is said and done, here are appropriate `pre` and `post` values for the character set in the question.

- `pre`: `"[:space:]({“[—–-"`
- `post`: `"][:space:])}”.?!,;:–—-"`

And the (I believe quite readable) code to generate those strings.

```
(setcar org-emphasis-regexp-components                              
  (concat                                                           
    ;; All whitespace characters.                                   
    "[:space:]"                                                     
    (string                                                         
      ;; Opening delimiters; the comments prevent check-parens from getting mad .
      ?( ;;)                                                        
      ?{ ;;}                                                        
      ?“ ;;”                                                        
      ?[ ;]                                                         
      ;; Dashes                                                     
      ?— ?– ?-))) ;; Do not move the dash. It will break the regexp.

  (setcar (nthcdr 1 org-emphasis-regexp-components)
    (concat
      (string ;[
         ?]) ;; Do not move the bracket. It will break the regexp.
      ;; All whitespace characters.
      "[:space:]"
      (string
        ;; Closing delimiters, with matching comments as above.
           ;;(
        ?) ;;{
        ?} ;;“
        ?”
        ;; Punctuation
        ?. ?? ?! ?, ?; ?:
        ;; Dashes
        ?– ?— ?-))) ;; Do not move the dash. It will break the regexp.
```

Comment: These are general restrictions on regexps and have nothing to do with `org-emphasis-regexp-components`. See e.g. [Special Characters in Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special) To quote: `To include a ‘]’ in a character alternative, you must make it the first character. For example, ‘[]a]’ matches ‘]’ or ‘a’. To include a ‘-’, write ‘-’ as the first or last character of the character alternative, or as the upper bound of a range. Thus, ‘[]-]’ matches both ‘]’ and ‘-’. `

Comment: Thank you! I really need to remember to read more carefully when handling regular expressions. Following the requirements, it very easily works. I've corrected the requirements and the code in my answer.